what do CPU Cycles (@ 4 GHz) and Time (At 1 Hz) mean?
Intel claims that the 14900K allows bursts of up to 6.0GHz, which means, i guess, that the processor can execute 6 billion instructions/cycles in one second.
in the following table, what do CPU Cycles (@ 4 GHz) and Time (At 1 Hz) mean?
one explanation I can imagine is, suppose there are 4 billion units of data, the CPU (@ 4 GHz) can manage to process the data in one second while reading the data from a 5400 RPM HDD  (At 1 Hz) takes 2.2 years.

I don't even imagine the keywords I could google with. any clue would be appreciated.

The "CPU Cycles (@ 4 GHz)" column is just the previous column times 4 GHz. For example, 3,000,000,000 ns × 4 GHz = 12,000,000,000. That's how many CPU cycles there would be in that time if the CPU was running at the fixed rate of 4 GHz (which modern CPUs generally don't). The "Time (At 1 Hz)" column is the previous column divided by 1 Hz. I wouldn't worry about it; I don't think whoever made that table had any profound point to make.

Additionally, "6.0GHz clock speed" doesn't mean "the processor can execute 6 billion instructions in one second". We live in a superscalar world, where the number of instructions per cycle can be greater than 1, and usually is.
